# How can I access variables displayed with dd( ) of Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, dd

I need to access to this id
here is the code I used to displayed with dd()

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    Storage::extend('google', function ($app, $config) {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setClientId($config['clientId']);
        $client->setClientSecret($config['clientSecret']);
        $client->refreshToken($config['refreshToken']);
        $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
        $adapter = new GoogleDriveAdapter($service, $config['folderId']);
        
        return new Filesystem($adapter);
    });

    $disk = Storage::disk('google');
    
    $disk->put('abc.txt', "eyyyertr");
    
    dd($disk);
    ///return view('welcome');
});
```

What I need is to get the variable I mentioned in the picture below, so I can delete the uploaded file with its own id

so far I tried :

```
$disk['driver']['adapter']
```

but it doens't work, it gives me this Error

```
Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter as array
```

[image]

What should I do ?

Comment: Try `$disk->driver->adapter` instead.

Comment: keep in mind that the `-` in front of `cacheFileObjectsByName` indicates that the property is private meaning the authors of this particular class did not intend for this property to be accessible outside this class. You might need to take a look at what public API that class exposes in case there is a way to get what you need or or find an alternative approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, Apparently we must create getters on each class
Here what worked for me

```
dd($disk->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getCacheFileObjectsByName()->id);
```

note each 'get....()' is written on used classes
example: in FilesystemAdapter.php class

```
public function getDriver()
{
   return $this->driver;
}
```

and the rest is the same.

also the 'cacheFileObjectsByName' was a private array, so the getter must be like so

```
public function getCacheFileObjectsByName()
{
   return array_values($this->cacheFileObjectsByName)[0];
}
```

..thank you for your helps